# some times camera preview freezing without touch on andoid webview app(not mobile webbrowser)

Tags: webview, getusermedia

Sometimes the camera preview is freezing without being touched in my Android WebView app (not in a mobile web browser). Please see the below video. I think I have to modify my Android program to solve this issue (possibly due to low battery problems), but I don't know what to do.

Link to video: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/gS0W_ku6t7E

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/2698

Suggested to add a spinner/animation helps to keep the video feed live.

I tested it on my project and it works for me.

```
<%-- Fixed webview bug camera video frozen --%>
<div style="background:linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.9), rgba(0,0,0,0.9)), url('../../Media/loading-small.gif') no-repeat center;">&nbsp;</div>
```